# grails including native code

Tags: grails, build, native-code, custom-build-step

I have a grails project that depends on some native code, which will vary depending on the platform. I would like store these in my dependency repository (e.g. nexus), rather than in the project directly since they are files that can be shared across multiple projects (it is 3rd party native code).

I start my app using `grails -Djava.library.path=/path/to/native run-app`

But I need a way to copy the appropriate native code (based on the platform) to `/path/to/native`

I've done this in a desktop application using maven, where I included a custom build step that copies the platform specific native code to `/path/to/native`, but I'm not sure how to do this in grails. Is creating a custom _Events.groovy the right approach or is there other ways to add this custom build step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails can use regular Maven dependencies by declaring them in the `dependencies {}` block in `BuildConfig.groovy`, and these will get copied into the WAR during the build. There's no need to include the library binaries in your Grails application source.

`_Events.groovy` is the appropriate place to add scripts to hook into the build process.

Comment: Thanks, Ken. Appreciate the response.